# Is there a way to run MIN on an entire table in a MySQL range query?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find a if the minium date value for a table exists with inside a particular range value.

So for the field `date_created` I want to find the minimum value for the field in the entire table as it exists for a particular user. But then I want to see if in a query, say between a particular month, if that minimum table value exists in that query.

I am also using a group by to get specific minimum values for a user. Here is my current query,

```
SELECT user_id,
       Min(date_created) AS first_date
FROM   user_transactions
WHERE  DATE BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2013-05-30'
GROUP  BY user_id
```

I'm seeing it only return the minimum date value in the range query, not in the entire table. I want the row to be omitted if the table minimum isn't in the range. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: use `WHERE` in conjunction to `MIN`?

Comment: @luiges90, yeah I tried that. It returns a single row with the min being contained with in the range. I also need to run a group by on another field in the table.

Comment: What's the query you are using? That make things much clearer...

Comment: @luiges90, edited and hopefully clarified the question

Comment: Did you mean : 
You want min value of every users that is within the range?

Comment: @Ramsharan, yes, edited again, sorry it's late :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your edited question :

The answer could be :

```
SELECT user_id, MIN(date_created) AS first_date
FROM user_transactions
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING first_date BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2013-05-30' ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery to select the minimum `date_created` for the specific user. Then check if the date is in the range.

```
SELECT
 u1.user_id, u1.date_created AS first_date
FROM
 user_transactions u1
WHERE
 u1.date_created =
 (
   SELECT MIN(u2.date_created)
   FROM user_transactions u2
   WHERE u2.user_id = u1.user_id
 )
 AND u1.date_created BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2013-05-30'
GROUP BY
 user_id;
```

---

Working [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69b5d/1)

Comment: Ah, that is a good idea, it just doesn't work with my group by to give me the first date for a particular user.

Comment: Your query makes complete sense to me, but it's still not working working for me.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Great to see honesty.

Comment: Ah got it working. Actually this version of the query is better suited for the specific thing I am doing (report builder in a BI tool) but I agree Ramsharan's version is probably a better general solution.